# Tie-breaking in sort

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of tuples.

The list is of the form

```
list=[(num1,distance1,blah1),.....]
```

I have to sort the list w.r.t. the distance but in case of a tie have to prefer the smaller num value.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: show us what you have done so far.

Comment: @user3100115 It's a huge implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm using binary heaps. I'm struggling to return the result in the correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `operator.itemgetter` to create a key function.

```
from operator import itemgetter

new_list = sorted(list, key=itemgetter(1,0))
```

Comment: More exactly `itemgetter(1, 0)` in his case.

Comment: How does this work, exactly? Python sorts by `itemgetter(1)` and, in the event that this applied to two tuples returns the same value, it sorts by `itemgetter(0)`? Or is there some sophisticated tuple-magic `sorted` does?

Comment: `itemgetter(1, 0)` returns a tuple containing the second and the first values of the provided list. When the key is an array, `sort` firsts sort using the first value, then the second and so on.